# Multiple SimpleMessageListenerContainer containers

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have 2 RabbitMQ queues that I am listening to. For 1 queue, I need a single consumer to make sure only one message is being processed at a time. 
The second queue can receive tons of messages in a second and I need to be able to consume many messages at a time.

I have the following code and it does work as I expect it to. But I want to see if there is a better way of doing this.

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setMessageConverter(Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE1);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[]{interceptor()});
    return container;
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container1(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setMessageConverter(Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE2);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[]{interceptor()});
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(queueService, "consume");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is absolutely correct. If you need different consumers for different queues, you have to configure different `ListenerContainer`s. You might consider to use Spring Integration AMQP Channel Adapters also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html